# curve equation from $\frac{1}{2^x}-\frac{1}{3^x}=\frac{1}{2^y}-\frac{1}{3^y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, conic-sections, lambert-w

Is there a way to find the equation of the curved part for this:

$$\frac{1}{2^x}-\frac{1}{3^x}=\frac{1}{2^y}-\frac{1}{3^y}$$ for $x$?
See [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2%5Ex-1%2F3%5Ex%3D1%2F2%5Ey-1%2F3%5Ey) for the plot.

The curve is crossing the line $y=x$ at $x=\log_{\frac{3}{2}}(\log_2(3))$

I tried several cases in geogebra, but without success. I don't even know if something fits.

Edit: [This equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E-x-3%5E-x%3C2%5E-y-3%5E-y) is very similar to [$x^y=y^x$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ey%3Cy%5Ex). I guess I'll end-up with a Lambert $W$ function.

Comment: Hmm, I do not know whether this goes in the direction you want to go... but just an idea:
$$\frac{1}{2^{m-d}}-\frac{1}{3^{m-d}}=\frac{1}{2^{m+d}}-\frac{1}{3^{m+d}}$$
$$ 2^{-m}(2^d-2^{-d}) =  3^{-m}(3^d-3^{-d}) $$ For $d \ne 0$:
$$ 1.5^m =  { \sinh(d \cdot \ln3 ) \over \sinh(d \cdot \ln2 ) } $$
$$ m = \log_{1.5}( { \sinh(d \cdot \ln3 ) \over \sinh(d \cdot \ln2 ) }) $$

Comment: ...ehhhmm : and then $[x,y] = [x(d),y(d)]=[m(d)-d , m(d)+d]$ are solutions of the equation.

Comment: @Gottfried Helms  Thanks. It was derived from $\frac{3^{y-x}-1}{2^{y-x}-1}=\frac{3^y}{2^y}$ when I was exploring the Waring's problem. I tried to get something out of your results, but I didn't get far. I should be back to it in a near future.

Comment: Substitute $\frac1{2^x}=t$ and use this [MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial)